# iPad crash after fast restart, when performing task at exit

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, crash

I'm working on an iPad app, targeting iOS 3.2 (so everyone can run it), and when the user presses the Home button, the app gets an applicationWillTerminate: message and it sends usage data to a server before it exits.

This all works fine. But if you exit and then restart the app before it's done exiting, it appears to crash.

The 5 seconds you get to clean up when the app is exiting begins once you get the applicationWillTerminate: message, but the app disappears immediately from the device, giving the user the opportunity to launch it again.

I think what's happening, is that they're just reactivating the app before it's done exiting, and so they're just jumping back into the first instance of the app just before it actually exits. So the second instance of the app appears to be crashing.

There is no crash log, and putting a log message into the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: doesn't produce any logs in the console from that second launching of the app. This is why I'm pretty sure it's not actually creating a second instance but just re-entering the first instance which is almost done exiting.

So are there any ideas out there about how to avoid this situation? It seems odd that you are given 5 seconds to perform actions on exit, but then this odd behaviour happens as a result.

I'm worried part of the problem is that the app is targeting iOS 3.2 and is actually exiting when the HOME button is pressed, and if it were just going into the background, this wouldn't be an issue. Sadly, changing that behaviour is just not an option at this moment.

Comment: Does this happen when there's no debugger attached? (I've definitely seen weird behavior in this arena when the debugger is attached that magically went away under normal operation.)

Comment: Yes it does. I'm worried the sending of data at exit is a red herring. It seems to happen even when the data isn't being sent, but it's much harder to reproduce. I'm wondering if its some kind of threading issue, like maybe a thread isn't shutting down correctly (or soon enough).

Comment: You need to keep a close watch on your threads. Are you using threads other than the main thread in your app or are you talking about system threads? Because you shouldn't have to worry about those. Are you relying on data, being sent or saved during shutdown, on startup? It be helpful to post your appDidFinishLaunching code.

Comment: I think the problem is I wasn't just doing an asynchronous web request, I was actually blocking the main thread waiting for the request to return, otherwise it's doesn't seem guaranteed it will send if you just "fire-and-forget". But it turns out blocking the main thread is a bad idea at exit time. The right thing to do is either use the synchronous call, or create a secondary thread to do the work of sending. The catch is, that second thread has to be a POSIX thread, not an NSThread, because NSThreads are detachable (iOS just kills them off at exit time).